# How to embed the certificate for the web socket in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, ssl, browser, websocket

I am working on an application that is suppose to receive the data over web sockets. I haven't worked with socket data before.

I am trying to directly connect to web socket server over wss from my Angular application. This however throws an ERR_CERT_INVALID error.

I assume, I need to provide some detail to the server for authentication in form of certificate keys.

How can I pass these details directly from my Angular10 client while creating the connection. Is it even possible to pass these details while making a connection from browser or do I need to use an intermediate server ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Validating the certificates for a connection is done inside the browser. There is no way for an Angular application to setup own certificate validation or add its own trusted certificates. To make it easy a publicly issued certificate should be used which automatically is checked and trusted by the browser. In case of a private certificate it would need to be explicitly added by all users to their browsers, i.e. there is no way to do this automatically from the Angular application.